# jquery hooks for finger swype?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so, i've built this site to put up some of my photos:

pics.nicecomeback.com

it's not using any standard jquery photo gallery .. implemented my own by capturing arrows and swapping page background to show next/previous photo.

to my surprise, this thing mostly just works when viewed on an android or iphone.

what i'd like to add, is mimic the arrows functionality when a user swypes left/right.

all i need is some way to capture the side swyping event. does JQuery have some utility for that ?

need something as light weight as possible. taking a look at [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/).. This is nice but kind of overkill for what i need.

Comment: Keep in mind that the overkill solution is more likely to support more devices and/or keep that support over the years. This may or may not be appealing given your DIY approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/) is pretty much it, a jQuery plugin for swipe event.